# Fazer select com LIKE e AND ao mesmo tempo

Tags: php, javascript, autocompletar

Tenho esse script que faz uma busca:

```js
$(function($) {
  $("#loc_menu").autocomplete({
    source: "php/search_cidades.php",
    minLength: 2,

    select: function(event, ui) {
      // Set autocomplete element to display the label
      this.value = ui.item.label;

      // Store value in hidden field
      $('#h_l').val(ui.item.id);

      // Prevent default behaviour
      return false;
    }
  });

  $("#loc_menu").click(function() {
    $('#h_l').val(0);
    $('#loc_menu').val('');
  });
});
```

```html
<?php
 /******* Conexão com o bando de dados *******/
 include "../Conexao/config.php";
 mysqli_select_db($config, $database_config);
 mysqli_set_charset($config,"utf8");
 /******* Conexão com o bando de dados *******/

 //get search term
 $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
 //$cidade_uf  = $_GET['cidade_uf'];

 $sql_1 = mysqli_query($config, "SELECT * FROM tb_sub_categorias WHERE sub_categoria LIKE '".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY sub_categoria ASC") or die(mysqli_error($config)); // LIMIT 5

 if(@mysqli_num_rows($sql_1) <= '0'){
  //echo "$erro"; 
  
  $sql_2 = mysqli_query($config, "SELECT * FROM tb_empresas WHERE razao_social LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' AND cidade_uf = '$cidade_uf' ORDER BY razao_social ASC") or die(mysqli_error($config)); // LIMIT 5

  if(@mysqli_num_rows($sql_2) <= '0'){
   $output_array[] = array( 
    'id' => '0'
    , 'label' => 'Nenhum resultado encontrado'
    , 'value' => 'Nenhum resultado encontrado'
   ); 
  }else{
   while($r_sql_2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_2)){
    //$selecao = $r_sql_2['razao_social'];
    //$data[]  = $selecao;
    
    $output_array[] = array( 
     'id' => "co_" . $r_sql_2['id']
     , 'label' => $r_sql_2['razao_social']
     , 'value' => $r_sql_2['razao_social']
    );     
   }
  }  
 }else{
  while($r_sql_1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_1)){
   //$selecao = $r_sql_1['sub_categoria'];
   //$data[]  = $selecao;
   
   $output_array[] = array( 
    'id' => "ca_" . $r_sql_1['id']
    , 'label' => $r_sql_1['sub_categoria']
    , 'value' => $r_sql_1['sub_categoria']
   );    
  }
 }

 //return json data
 echo json_encode($output_array);

 mysqli_close($config); 
?>
```

Precisaria refinar esse busca.
Estou tentando fazer dessa forma:

```
$sql_1 = mysqli_query($config, "SELECT * FROM tb_sub_categorias WHERE sub_categoria LIKE '".$searchTerm."%' AND id_sub_cat IN (1306, 1405) ORDER BY sub_categoria ASC") or die(mysqli_error($config));
```

Tenho uma tabela de categorias e outra de clientes/categorias.

Gostaria que o script buscasse as categorias que estão atreladas aos clientes cadastrados, ao invés de buscar todas as categorias.

Todas as tentativas que fiz não fazem a pesquisa refinar.

Comment: Essa query procura as subcategories com id 1306 ou 1405 e que comecem com o termo de pesquisa. É isso que queres?

Comment: Esses ids foram um exemplo. Se for seguir essa dinâmica, farei um select antes e extrairei de um array os ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você necessita de um `Join` e a forma mais simples é ter uma `FK` de `sub_categoria` em cliente.

```
SELECT * FROM TB_SUB_CATEGORIA SC, CLIENTES CL
WHERE SC.CD_SUB_CATEGORIA = CL.CD_SUB_CATEGORIA
AND SC.SUB_CATEGORIA LIKE '".$SEARCHTERM."%'
AND SC.ID_SUB_CAT IN (1306, 1405)
```

Talvez necessite modificar uma coisa ou outra, mas deve ser isso, espero ter ajudado!